# Accented characters in Chrome Packaged app webview not showing up

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am developing a Chrome Packaged app that has a webview in it. The problem is that I cannot type any sort of accented character (such as é, ç, ê) in a text input that is inside the webview. When I try to type **é**, for instance, I only get **e** in the text field. Strangely I can copy and paste accented characters into the webview text field without a problem.

Text inputs that are outside the webview work ok. This issue only seems to happen when running the packaged app on Mac OSX (It works fine on Windows). Other official sample apps that use webviews also have the same issue.

I have already checked if UTF-8 is being used by both the app and the webview itself, and it is.

Any idea of what might be happening?

Comment: How are you typing those accent keys? I've tried to reproduce with a <input> in the <webview>, I see accent chars. e.g. I've typed option+e then e to get é.

Comment: I have my Macbook Pro keyboard set to U.S. international, exactly the same as in Windows. It does not seem to be related to my keyboard settings, otherwise the text input outside the Webview wouldn't work. Correct?

Comment: Just typed some german umlauts like: äöüß into a webviews input field on my macbook. No problem.

Comment: How did you type those characters? In French and Portuguese I have to type ' and then  e  to get é.
The same goes for ê and etc. This is what is not working.

Comment: Just tested with the webview sample (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/webview), adding a <input type="text"> in one of the webviews and typing Portuguese accented letters in a US International keyboard using dead keys. Works perfectly in a Linux box and Chrome 32. @rodd, could you publish a simplified version of your code somewhere we can access, please?

Comment: This seems to only happen in MacOSX when the U.S. International - PC keyboard is used. To replicate the issue:
1. Add the U.S. International - PC keyboard on MacOSX's Systems Preferences
2. Open a packaged app with a webview that either has an input text or textarea in int. 3. Try to type the following character (for instance) ' and then e to produce: é

Comment: I think I can trigger this bug with the presence of another input element inside the app. I've filed http://crbug.com/341185

Comment: Thank you, lazyboy.
I have also filed a bug report: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=338586

Comment: This was fixed in https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?view=rev&revision=249935, try current chrome canary which has the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like lazyboy commented, this has been fixed since Chrome 34. It was actually a bug in previous versions of Chrome.